# Header - Downloaded Gzip Not In Gzip Format, Correct On Server

Tags: php, download, gzip

I'm trying to create, download then remove a gzipped file.

The file created on the server is correct. I can download it with a direct link and the file decompresses correctly locally.

If I use header(), the file won't decompress and gives an error "Not In Gzip Format". It seems like I have to use header(), to be able to unlink().

The gist of the code is:

```
# This creates the gz file correctly..
$tar = 'meta-info.tar';
$gz = $tar.'.gz';
$p = new PharData($tar);
$p->compress(Phar::GZ)->buildFromDirectory('../');

# This creates the dialog then removes the file correctly..
header('Content-Type:'.mime_content_type($gz));
header('Content-Length:'.filesize($gz));
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=$gz");
flush();
readfile($gz);
unlink($gz);

# ...but the downloaded file is not correct.
```

Oddly, a 'zip' file downloads and decompresses correctly.

I've looked all over stackoverflow and tried a number of things, but nothings working.. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what Content-Type header is actually sent? Use your browsers development console to examine the response you get.

Comment: You are not able to see _what_? If you download a file, then certainly you performed a request and that certainly is shown in the development console. You know how to open that and use the "network" tab in there?

Comment: AFAICS `application/x-gzip` is not amongst the official mime types generally supported...

Comment: Maybe the activated zip compression module of the http server intercepts? Sounds odd, though...

Comment: Did you look at that data? It's the start of a web page: `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><meta charset="ut`. What does the entire page say? You may just be getting a not found error in the form of a web page.

Comment: Maybe a previous result is cached?

Comment: Can you try header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); instead of the mime type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that header info had already been sent.

Using ob_end_clean() fixed it (the structure of the page can't be changed).

```
ob_end_clean();
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=$gz");
header('Content-Type:application/x-gzip');
header('Content-Length:'.filesize($gz));
flush();
readfile($gz);
unlink($gz);
```

Comment: In my case this code works absolute fine                                                       
                                                                                                                       
ob_end_clean();
header("Content-type:application/tar+gzip");
header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
readfile(''.$filename.'');